# Unable to see image on Google app engine web

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I Just want to show image on Google app Engine Website. 
I am new to Google app engine.
I made changes in App.yaml and Main.py
app.yaml looks like :

```
application: simplegraph-007
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
 static_files: favicon.ico
 upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
 static_dir: static/images
 mime_type: image/png

- url: .*
  script: main.app

 libraries:
 - name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Main.py looks like.

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("""<img src = 'D:\download\rel.png/>""")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

What else I need to change.
I hope to get help.

Thanks,

Comment: check the file name `script: Main.app` or `script: Main.py`

Answer (score 2):

Copy the image to static/images directory in your project.  From a browser, this path is "/images".

If you just want to show the image, in your browser, go to:
http://localhost:8080/images/rel.png

To see the image from the cloud, deploy your app and see the image at:
http://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/images/rel.png

To use that image within an html page, use:

```
<img src="/images/rel.png" />
```

Comment: I did the changes in the Code. But Still it I am not able to see any image. I made an folder in my project file which name "image"  
my code looks like 

    self.response.out.write(<img src = 'image\rel.png'/>)

It shows a blank screen in /image/rel.png

Comment: I hope to get an answer Thanks

Comment: The main handler of your code doesn't really add any value.  If you want to see the image and have your server running locally - you should see it at http://localhost:8080/images/rel.png  Just be sure you see the image on your file system in the correct directory relative to your app.yaml file.

Comment: @hrishabhupadhyay To verify the app is running correctly, you can change MainHandler to output text, you then should see "Hello World" in the browser: self.response.out.write("Hello World")

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting invalid HTML. It is missing the closing single quote `'` and has an extra trailing `/`.

```
<img src = 'D:\download\rel.png/>
```

Also you are trying to serve an image directly from your filesystem which *may* work locally, but it will not work when deployed to app engine.