# Unable to add Image on Google App Engine Website

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am Trying to make a simple website with a image in it by using google app Engine. I am unable to make it.

My App.yaml code is below:

```
application: simplegraph-007
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
handlers:

- url: /image/.*
  static_dir: static/image/.*



- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

My Main.py looks like:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("<img src ='/image/Ris.jpeg'/>")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

My log is here:

```
INFO     2015-10-19 18:46:39,111 module.py:786] default: "GET /image/Ris.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 154
```

I hope to have help from you.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of earlier question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175530/unable-to-see-image-on-google-app-engine-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve static images like this.

In app.yaml

```
- url: /image   
  static_dir: image
```

In your app root folder, create a folder `/image` and put `Ris.jpeg` there.

Folder layout should look similar to this

```
+ image
    |
    -- Ris.jpeg
- app.yaml
- main.py
```

`GET /image/Ris.jpeg` will now return the image file.

Also see [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles).

Comment: I have made a folder name "image" in my root file and it contain Ris.jpeg
but still i am unable to add images

Comment: @hrishabhupadhyay what do you mean with "add images"?

Comment: I just want to show an image on my website no text @timcastelijins

Comment: @hrishabhupadhyay I just copy pasted your code with my additions, it works. I have no idea what you're doing that breaks it

Comment: sorry if you don't mind can you send me the code to my email ID   and also I am not using eclispe    can you just show me whole code again as i am new to Google app engine launcher. And also I am running on "localhost:8080" it is showing blank screen

Comment: @hrishabhupadhyay I don't see the point. All the code you need is here on this page

Comment: IT worked. Now I am haveing problem in deploying As When i click the deploy button in google app engine nothing happened? Is there any problem in Google app Engine??

Comment: @hrishabhupadhyay I don't know , that is another problem

Comment: @hrishabhupadhyay I see you've opened a new question, I figure this one is solved.. please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs when you start your app locally. I am sure it is printing an error. This is invalid for static_dir

```
- url: /image/.*
  static_dir: static/image/.*
```

It does not need a wildcard. It should read:

```
- url: /image
  static_dir: static/image
```

Your image in your local filesystem should be `static/image/Ris.jpeg`.